# how to pass an object by reference to be used by another file

Tags: c++, oop, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I want to access this function in a file known as MinPriority.cpp:

```
MinPriority::priority& MinPriority::HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(*this) //dequeue's min element of tree
{
    MinPriority::priority& min = heapArray.front();
    heapArray.erase(heapArray.begin());
    MIN_HEAPIFY(0);
    return min;
}
```

It is supposed to dequeue an element from the vector `heapArray` and pass the object `priority` into another file known as Graph.cpp.  Here is where the function is called in Graph.cpp...

```
void Graph::MST_PRIM()
{
    MinPriority priority;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i != adjList.size(); i++)
    {
        priority.createArray(adjList[i].front().m_vertex, *this);
    }
    while(priority.queue_Empty() == false)
    {
        priority& u = priority.HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(/*...*/); //graph.cpp 88
    }

}
```

class MinPriority is declared as: (sketched it up for simplicity)

```
class MinPriority
{
private:
    class priority
    {
    public:
        priority(string preVertex, string vertex, int weight)
        {
            m_preVertex = preVertex;
            m_vertex = vertex;
            m_weight = weight;
        }
        ~priority(){}
        string m_preVertex;
        string m_vertex;
        int m_weight;
    };
    vector<priority> heapArray;
public:
        //member functions are included here...
};
```

basically, in the end, I want to be able to pop stuff out of heapArray, pass it to functions in Graph.cpp and possibly modify things already in the heapArray from Graph.cpp.  I never need push things onto the data structure as they are already there (because of a function not shown). Error:

```
$ make -f makefile.txt
g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -c Graph.cpp
Graph.cpp: In member function `void Graph::MST_PRIM()':
Graph.cpp:88: error: `u' undeclared (first use this function)
Graph.cpp:88: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
Graph.cpp:88: error: no matching function for call to `MinPriority::HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN()'
MinPriority.h:39: note: candidates are: MinPriority::priority& MinPriority::HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(MinPriority::priority&)
Graph.cpp: At global scope:
Graph.cpp:97: warning: unused parameter 'vertex'
makefile.txt:9: recipe for target `Graph.o' failed
make: *** [Graph.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Why do you have `*this` in the `HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN` parameter list? That won't compile.

Comment: It worked in another function that I got helped on in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723876/how-do-i-pass-an-object-by-reference-inside-parameters

Comment: That's passing *to* a function, not in the function declaration. What exactly is the problem you're having? What's your error?

Comment: Ill post it above... edited.

Comment: priority& HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(priority&);  theres the declaration where the MinPriority.h:39 error occurs

Comment: The problem I am having is listed above, I simply just dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with this code:

```
 MinPriority::priority& MinPriority::HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(*this) //dequeue's min element of tree
 {
   MinPriority::priority& min = heapArray.front();
   heapArray.erase(heapArray.begin());
   MIN_HEAPIFY(0);
   return min;
 }
```

But you have a few issues here:

1. The method has no argument type, it just has *this which makes no sense.
2. You are returning a reference to a temporary, this is undefined behaviour and will likely crash.

I think what you actually wanted was a wrapper method to return the front of the deque and remove it:

```
 MinPriority::priority MinPriority::PopFront()
 {
   // Copy of the front element
   MinPriority::priority min = heapArray.front();

   // Remove/destroy the front element
   heapArray.erase(heapArray.begin());

   // Return the copy
   return min;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that, the problem I have been having is actually accessing the function (the reason I asked the question.)

Comment: refer to graph.cpp:88 in my question...  WHat could I do to properly access what PopFront() returns?

Comment: g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -c Graph.cpp
Graph.cpp: In member function `void Graph::MST_PRIM()':
Graph.cpp:88: error: expected `;' before "u"
Graph.cpp:88: warning: statement has no effect

Comment: I tried   `MinPriority::priority u = priority.HEAP_EXTRACT_MIN(); `  gonna see if it works.